# How do I find out what font a text control in a C++ dialog is using? Or, what is this font?

Tags: mfc

I want to be able to create mock-ups of dialogs for UI design documents.  I would like to use the same font that current dialogs are using.  The project uses C++ and MFC, developed using Visual Studio 2019 on a Win10 box.  Where can I look to find out what font is being used for a particular text control?

Or, perhaps more simply, can you tell me what fonts are used on [this little sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnOpJ.jpg)?

Comment: Do you know which version of Visual Studio the project was created with and which project template was used?

Comment: It was probably created with the C++ MFC App template, but I don't know how long ago, so I don't know what version of Visual Studio.  Probably fairly recent.

Comment: Do you have the source code? You should be able to tell from that.